# Perl: using grep to extract a pattern matching substr of a file line

Tags: regex, perl, grep

i have the following content in a file:

gi|***170570902***|gb|ABLA01000008.1|  0.457  24  0.581  24  0.876  11  0.744   0.669 Y  0.450      SignalP-noTM

For every line in the file I would like to extract the number highlighted above and push it to an array. I'm trying to grep this number and extract it from the matched line, but I don't seem to find the right way to do it.

Here's what I have in mind:

```
while ($sec_gi = <IN_SIDS>){
    $sec_gi =~ s/[0-9]{5,}/$&/;
    print $sec_gi."\n";
}
```

$& is supposed to be the exact match string. With this I get the matched line EXCEPT the match pattern, which is exactly the opposite to what I want.

Could anyone pls help?

Thanks!

Comment: You are substituing `[0-9]{5,}` by itself, so no changes at all.

Comment: A) You're substituting when all you want to do is match and extract. B) Your pattern could match 01000008 in the above string too; use the delimiters in your pattern and group the numerals.

Comment: You are using a direct filehandle (IN_SIDS) which is not modern practice. I suggest using an indirect/lexical filehandle.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `split` is the simplest solution (ETA optimized):

```
while (<IN_SIDS>) {
    my $nums  = (split /\|/, $field, 3)[1];
    print "$nums\n";
    push @array, $nums;
}
```

I did a benchmark to compare the efficiency to a regex solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = "gi|170570902|gb|ABLA01000008.1| 0.457 24 0.581 24 0.876 11 0.744 0.669 Y 0.450 SignalP-noTM";

use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

cmpthese(shift, {
        'Regex' => \&regex,
        'Split' => \&splitting
    });

sub regex {
    if ($data =~ /^[^|]+\|(\d{5,})\|/) {
        return $1;
    }
}

sub splitting {
    return (split /\|/, $data, 3)[1];
}
```

The result is a draw:

```
tlp@ubuntu:~/perl$ perl tx.pl 1000000
           Rate Split Regex
Split 2083333/s    --   -2%
Regex 2127660/s    2%    --
```

Thanks M42 for advice in comments. I picked the `split` solution for simplicity and easy maintenance, not performance, but as of now, it is equal to a regex solution.

Comment: @M42 I disagree in regards to "best", if you don't care about the other fields it's a waste to make a split array from every field. Just match `\|(\d{5,0})\|` and pull out the `$1`

Comment: @dlamblin: You could use the `LIMIT` parameter : `split /\|/, $fields, 2`

Comment: @dlamblin That depends on what the OP is aiming for. This is a safe and simple solution, IMO, and the cost will be measured in seconds, even for large data sets.

Comment: If you remove the first split (on space) that isn't mandatory, the benchmark gives closer results.

Comment: @M42 yes the limit parameter (3) certainly improves this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just

`$sec_gi =~ /([0-9]{5,})/;`

print "$1\n";

Comment: `print "$1\n" if $sec_gi ...` or you risk printing bad values of `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$sec_gi =~ s/.*?\|(\d{5,}).*/\1/;
```

However if it's always in the 2nd column you can use split:

```
@lst = split('\|', $sec_gi );
$sec_gi = $lst[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Might as well give you answer #3:

```
# Declare Array outside the loop
my @my_array;
while ( $sec_gi = <IN_SIDS> ){
    chomp $sec_gi;

    # Test if this field actually exists

    if ( $sec_gi =~ /([0-9]{5,})/ ) {

        # Field exists, push it into your array (or print it)\

        push @my_array, $1;
    }
    else {

        # Field doesn't exist: Take appropriate action (which might mean none)

        print "Field not found\n";
    }
}

# Array @my_array has all of your values

yadda, yadda, yadda
```

By the way, this will locate the field no matter where on the line it occurs. If this number will only be in field #1, you want to use `split`:

```
my @my_array;
while ( $sec_gi = <IN_SIDS> ) {
    chomp $sec_gi;
    @sec_gi_array = split /\|/, $sec_gi;
    if ( $sec_gi_array[1] =! /[0-9]{5,}/ ) {
         push @my_array, $sec_gi_array[1];
    }
    else {
         print "Field not found\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value is always your second field you could use this:

```
while ($sec_gi = <IN_SIDS>) {
  if ($sec_gi =~ m/^[^|]*\|([^|]+)/) {
    print "$1\n";
  }
}
```

If some of the second fields are not always the one you want (IE you only want 5 or more numbers, as implied) then you could be more specific:

```
while ($sec_gi = <IN_SIDS>) {
  if ($sec_gi =~ m/^[^|]*\|(\d{5,})/) {
    print "$1\n";
  }
}
```

If your perl script is doing ONLY this, you can use the gnu coreutil `cut` (`man cut`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have to use grep, the following short program will work.

Hope this helps.

Caitlin

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array;

for ( <DATA> )
{
    push @array, $1 if /gi\|(\d+)\|/;
}

for (@array) {
    print "$_\n";
}

__DATA__
gi|170570902|gb|ABLA01000008.1| 0.457 24 0.581 24 0.876 11 0.744 0.669 Y 0.450 SignalP-noTM
gi|178370902|gb|ABLA01000008.1| 0.457 24 0.581 24 0.876 11 0.744 0.669 Y 0.450 SignalP-noTM
gi|170593502|gb|ABLA01000008.1| 0.457 24 0.581 24 0.876 11 0.744 0.669 Y 0.450 SignalP-noTM
gi|170578993|gb|ABLA01000008.1| 0.457 24 0.581 24 0.876 11 0.744 0.669 Y 0.450 SignalP-noTM
gi|170898368|gb|ABLA01000008.1| 0.457 24 0.581 24 0.876 11 0.744 0.669 Y 0.450 SignalP-noTM
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify a capture group:

```
  while ($sec_gi = <IN_SIDS>){
     $sec_gi =~ s/^.*([0-9]{5,}).*$/$1/;
     print $sec_gi."\n";
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Fair enough, I've fixed the regex.